# shooting a projectile from a location to the mouse location

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a project I have working on. I am trying to create a cannon that can shoot a cannonball. Now I have code that allows me to draw a ball will gravity and a floor where the cannonball bounces. I want to find a way to use the mouse to control exactly where the ball is being shot.

if someone could help me figure it out I would greatly appreciate it.
thanks

here is the js that I am working with

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

// const mouse = {
//   x: 0,
//   y: 0
// }
const mouse = {
x: innerWidth / 2,
y: innerHeight / 2
}
const center = {x: canvas.width / 2,
y: canvas.height / 2}

// Event Listeners
addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
mouse.x = event.clientX
mouse.y = event.clientY - canvas.height

angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y, mouse.x)

//let distBetween = function(p1, p2){
//return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((p2.x - p1.x), 2) + Math.pow((p2.y - p1.y), 2));
//}

//let angleBetween = function(p1, p2){
//return Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)
//}
//})

addEventListener('resize', () =\> {
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

init()
})
let angle = 0

// Objects
class Particle {
constructor(x, y, radius, color, distanceFromCenter) {
this.x = x
this.y = y
this.radius = radius
this.color = color
this.distanceFromCenter = distanceFromCenter
}

    draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
        c.fillStyle = this.color
        c.fill()
        c.closePath()
    }
    
    
    update() {
        this.draw()
        this.x = (0) + (this.distanceFromCenter + 30) * Math.cos(angle)
        this.y = canvas.height + (this. distanceFromCenter +30) * Math.sin(angle)
    }

}
class Cannonball {
constructor(x, y, radius, color){
this.x = x
this.y = y
this.radius = radius
this.color = color
this.dx = Math.cos(angle) \* 2;
this.dy = Math.sin(angle) \* 2;
this.velocity = 2
this.gravity = 1
this.friction = -0.75
}
draw(){
c.beginPath()
c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI \* 2, false)
c.fillStyle = 'blue'
c.fill()
c.closePath()
}

    update(){
        if (this.y + this.radius + 5 > canvas.height){
            this.velocity = -this.velocity * this.gravity
        } else {
          this.velocity += this.gravity
        }
        
        this.y += this.velocity
        this.velocity += this.friction 
        this.draw()
    
    
    }

}

// let cannonball = new Cannonball(center.x, center.y, 30, 'blue')

// particle Implementation
let particleCount = 400
let particles;

// let cannonballCount = 400
let cannonballs;

function init() {
particles = \[\]
for (let i = 0; i \< particleCount; i++) {
const x = 0 + i \* Math.cos(1)
const y = canvas.height + this. distanceFromCenter \* Math.sin()
particles.push(new Particle(x, y, 30, 'red', i))
}

cannonballs = \[\]
}

// Animation Loop
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate)

    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    
    particles.forEach((particle) => {
        particle.update()
    })
    cannonballs.forEach(cannonball => {
        cannonball.update()
       })

}

init()
animate()

addEventListener('click', (event) =\> {
mouse.x = event.clientX
mouse.y = event.clientY

    cannonballs.push(new Cannonball(mouse.x, mouse.y, 30, 'blue',  {
        x: Math.cos(angleIncrement * i),
        y: Math.sin(angleIncrement * i)
    
    })

}
```